# Change site language programmatically

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I need to change site language programmatically in Liferay and Im stuck. I thought that I can use LanguageUtil class, but I dont know how.

Is there any way, to change Liferay language programmatically? (I know I can do that in administration panel, but I need to have that feature in my code also).

Now my code looks like this:

```
@ResourceMapping("changeLanguageToEnglish")
public void changeLanguageToEnglish(){
        LanguageUtil langUtil = new LanguageUtil();
        //langUtil.setLanguage(language);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do this using the portal-ext.properties:

```
#
# Set the default locale used by Liferay. This locale is no longer set at
# the VM level. See LEP-2584.
#
user.country=US
user.language=en
```

Also by a hook

```
<hook>
     <language-properties>content/Language_en.properties</language-properties>
     <language-properties>content/Language_fa.properties</language-properties>
</hook>
```

And through a portlet

[Change languaje portlet](https://web.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/32627016)

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try but I think you have to change the locale set is the user session:

```
String languageId = "en_US";
Locale locale = LocaleUtil.fromLanguageId(languageId);
session.setAttribute(org.apache.struts.Globals.LOCALE_KEY, locale);
```